# Using dplyr to connect to SSL-encrypted remote database

Tags: r, ssl, odbc, rodbc, dplyr

I would like to use the `dplyr` package in R but to connect to a remote database that is SSL-encrypted. How do I set up a workaround here? I'm thinking of setting up a backend that uses the RODBC package. Is this possible?

Comment: Which database? Unfortunately you can't connect to a postgres db via SSL because RPostgreSQL doesn't support SSL connections.  Connecting via RODBC is an option, but there's no RODBC backend for dplyr yet (it would be relatively simple to write one)

Comment: What are the steps to writing a new backend?

Comment: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/vignettes/new-sql-backend.Rmd - let me know if you get stuck, I'm happy to help out.

Comment: Thanks, Hadley. When/if successful making the RODBC backend, I'll post some useful code on Github.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you can connect to a an SSL-encrypted connection with `dplyr` and it's easy.

You just need to pass the parameters for your connection within the `dbname` parameter, like this (this is a postgresql example):

```
db <- src_postgres(dbname="dbname=my_db sslcert=my_cert.crt sslkey=my_key.key sslmode=require", user="username", host="your.host.com")
```